# Arcpy multivalue add to where clause

Tags: arcpy, splitting, array

I'm trying to create my first tool, where will be possible to insert multivaule into process. I need to insert these values to "where clause" but in my code it inserts only one value. Here is my simple code:

```
import arcpy
stands = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
protecAreas = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
protecAreasList = protecAreas.split(";")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(stands,'standmap', """ [ARTYPE] IN ('{}')""".format("','".join(protecAreasList)))
```

Can someone advise me where could be a problem ? Attribute ARTYPE has String data type. In parameter properties, MultiValue is set to Yes and Filter has Value List where I added several string values.

Comment: I'd use tuple (list), no need formatting

Comment: Is your data in a personal geodatabase? See: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm